# Yocto - size of a partition

Tags: linux, yocto, partitioning, bitbake

I am working with Linux built with Yocto. I would like to decrease the size of partition with rootfs. Now, the partition size is twice as large as the space occupied by packages. Eventually, the partition will be mounted in read-only mode, so I do not need so much free space. In a `<meta-mylayer>/layer.conf` I set the following variables:

```
IMAGE_OVERHEAD_FACTOR = "1.0"
IMAGE_ROOTFS_EXTRA_SPACE = "0"
```

it seems that these variables affect the partition size, but not in the way I expect. When I set

```
IMAGE_OVERHEAD_FACTOR = "0.3"
```

the size of a partition was nearly equal to the space occupied by packages. But as I understand from Yocto Manual, this variable should not be less than 1.

What else can I do to reduce the partition size?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: You can try to reduce the number of packages you have on your images or remove debug pakcages.